# Xcode 8.3 Linker Warnings

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, xcode8, linker-warning

Trying to Archive app prior to submitting to Apple. Warning limit exceeded - showing first 200 warnings only. Sample warnings:

```
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: 'sharedInstance.sharedInstance'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_literal_global'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
```

Using Xcode 8.3.3. Swift 3. Relevant Firebase pod entries:

```
Using Firebase (4.0.2)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.1)
Using FirebaseAuth (4.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.2)
Using FirebaseDatabase (4.0.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.0)
Using FirebaseMessaging (2.0.0)
Using FirebaseStorage (2.0.0)
```

I had this problem a while back and Firebase 3.16 seemed to have fixed it but now the warnings are back. Warnings come only on Archive. Anybody else reliving this situation?

Answer (score -2):

After importing the AdMob SDK, when I archived my project ( workspace), I had the following warning:

> ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'

I've found a way to get rid of it:

```
Target \ Build Settings \ Build Options \ Enable bitcode = NO
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I think that Bitcode is needed for my app. I'm still looking/waiting for some other solution.

Comment: @vikesh I don't think this is a valid solution, you're disabling a feature

Comment: why you're disabling an important feature for solving a simple issue?